# How to get Visual Studio Code to navigate to a React component's source file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Consider a typical ReactJS file, like:

```
import Popup from 'components/Popup/Popup';

// ...

<Popup
  trigger={
    <SVG src={pinIcon} className={pinClassName} />
  }
  content={pinTooltipText}
  position="bottom center"
  hideOnScroll
  className="popup-xl--hide"
/>
```

In VS Code, I want to go to the file that is my component, so jump to components/Popup/Popup. Using Go To Definition:

[image: Go To Definition in VS Code]

It sends me up to the import declaration. I can't jump to that file. This is a pain to manage as we have dozens of components and properties moving through them all. Being able to quickly navigate "down" the component stack by going to each definition would be mind-numbingly awesome.

Comment: It's because you're using a webpack alias. https://blog.andrewray.me/autocomplete-es-modules-webpack-vscode/

Comment: tbh when I press F12 it takes me to the class not the import

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have **import aliases, through webpack or babel**, you can create a [`jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) with the [`paths` property in the `compilerOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases).

Here's a Next project's `jsconfig.json` configured for `@/` aliases to the `src/` directory.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    ".next",
    ".cache",
    "bundles",
    "out"
  ],
  "include": [
    "pages/**/*",
    "src/**/*",
  ]
}
```

It may be needed to restart VS Code, then you should be able to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click any `<Component>` or import paths to navigate to it.

[image: VS Code component navigation]

Comment: I was using .jsx files for react component and for me ```"jsx": "react",``` option made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing `flow-bin` solved the problem, I got this warning from vs-code while working on react project.

```
npm install flow-bin -g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go up to the listing of the item within the `import` statement and hit [F12] again, you'll get this window:

[image: image of expanded Component definition]

Within that window, you can double click anywhere within that left hand window, and it will open the file to that location.

[image]

Comment: thats the issue i don't want this window; i want to open it directly

Answer (score 0):

for me the first code did not work, I spend a few to fixing it. here is my code:

jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*":["src/*"],
      "root/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    ".next",
    ".cache",
    "bundles",
    "out"
  ],
  "include": [
    "build/**/*",
    "server/**/*",
    "e2e/**/*",
    "pages/**/*",
    "src/**/*",
    "stories/**/*"
  ]
}
```